# Adding header and footer to PDF generated using rst2pdf and Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, rst2pdf

I have inherited a user guide that is built using reStructuredText and Sphinx, from which we want to (and can) produce a PDF using rst2pdf integration with Sphinx.  The one thing that we'd like to do is apply custom headers and footers to each page of the document (a'la "Draft - Not for Release" or "Version x.y.z"), but there isn't an obvious (to me) way to do this. The rst2pdf command supports specifying `--footer="..."` and `--header="..."`, but there doesn't seem to be an analogous option in the PDF configuration directives that one can specify in the Sphinx `conf.py`. Although RST does support header and foot directives, the Sphinx documentation explicitly warns against using them.

I *think* it might be possible to set this up using rst2pdf stylesheets, but I'm also having a bit of a time understanding how custom stylesheets interact with / extend / override existing stylesheets (if at all).

So what I am looking for is some guidance on how to get headers and footers added to each page cleanly using rst2pdf and Sphinx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I came up with is from piecing together information from:

- The `rst2pdf` documentation's discussion of [styles](https://rst2pdf.org/static/manual.html#styles) and [multiple stylesheets](https://rst2pdf.org/static/manual.html#multiple-stylesheets), which taught me that ordering of stylesheets matter and that custom stylesheets only need to define what is being *overridden* or added to previous stylesheets
- The [rst2pdf source code for built-instyles](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf/tree/6aac907f33ff9a026ef0bf6f0c89b41229b8d673/rst2pdf/styles) which shows that the stylesheets are best represented as YAML, and how they are structured, along with the [source for the rst2pdf style Python module](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf/blob/6aac907f33ff9a026ef0bf6f0c89b41229b8d673/rst2pdf/styles.py) to better understand how rst2pdf resolves the locations and extensions for the stylesheet files
- An [rst2pdf issues that has an example of rendering a footer with a stylesheet](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf/issues/926)

So what I did was create a stylesheet named `draft.yaml` and place it a `_styles` subdirectory of the document source code, which looked like:

```
pageTemplates:
    decoratedPage:
        defaultFooter: |
            .. class:: right

            ###Page###


            .. class:: draft

            DRAFT - DO NOT RELEASE


        defaultHeader: &draftCentered |

            .. class:: draft

            DRAFT - DO NOT RELEASE


    mainPage: &draftTopAndBottom
        defaultFooter: *draftCentered
        defaultHeader: *draftCentered
        showFooter: true
        showHeader: true

    coverPage: *draftTopAndBottom

    emptyPage: *draftTopAndBottom


styles:
    draft: {alignment: center, parent: bodytext, fontName: fontSansBold}
```

noting that the stylesheet processor supports anchors and aliases, that I am simply modifying existing page templates to include a default header and footer on all of the pages, and that I could define and use my own style to apply in the header and footer. I had wanted try using table syntax to place the page number and footer banner on the same line like can be done in the body of the document as [shown here](https://github.com/tonioo/rst2pdf/blob/master/doc/manual.txt), but it kept trying to treat the table syntax as a reference substitution.

To get this working with Sphinx and rst2pdf, I needed to add some additional configuration information in `conf.py` - first by adding `rst2pdf.pdfbuilder` to the list of `extensions`, and then the following variable definitions to control the PDF rendering:

```
# -- Options for PDF output ----------------------------------------------
pdf_documents = [('index', u'mydoc', u'My Documentation', u'My Project'),]
pdf_stylesheets = ['sphinx', 'letter', 'draft']
pdf_style_path = ['source/_styles']
```

With this configuration and the stylesheet in place, running sphinx with `pdf` builder the  will apply the built-in `sphinx` and `letter` *rst2pdf* stylesheets on top of the rst2pdf defaults, and then my custom `draft` rst2pdf stylesheet, and produce the desired banner text at the top and bottom of each page.